# Erro ao compilar ionic - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-cordova, ionic3

tudo bem? Estou tendo problemas ao compilar o APK pelo ionic.
Já removi o Android Studio e baixei novamente. Mas não funcionou.

Se eu tentar compilar pelo terminal ele da erro, mas se eu importar o projeto gradle para o Android Studio ele compila e o APP funciona perfeitamente, mas esse processo demora muito. Vejam o erro que da ao executar "ionic cordova build android"

```
Running command - failed![ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

    (truncated) ... figure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at 
    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at 
    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at 
    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at 
    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at 
    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at 
    org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at 
    org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at 
    org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at 
    org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at 
    org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at 
    org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script 
    '/Users/pedrodaher/iConexBaixa/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' 
    line: 64

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools 
    version 19.1.0 or higher.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
    --debug option to get more log output.
```

> **Ionic info:**

**cli packages:** (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

- @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0

**global packages:**

- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

**local packages:**

- @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
- Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
- Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

**System:**

- ios-deploy : 1.9.2
- Node       : v6.11.0
- npm        : 5.3.0
- OS         : macOS Sierra
- Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235

**Misc:**

- backend : legacy

Comment: Pelo que entendi você tem que instalar o SDK Build Tools. Você tem o SDK do Android instalado?

Comment: @LeandroSimões tudo bem? Eu tenho sim o SDK Build Tools, instalei ele pelo Android Studio 3.0

Comment: @PedroDaher você tem a variável ANDROID_HOME configurada e apontada corretamente para a pasta do SDK?

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática fui dar uma pesquisada e vi que realmente estava apontando para uma pasta antiga. Fiz a alteração usando o link [ANDROID_HOME SET] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x) e funcionou! Muito obrigado, poderia escrever uma resposta para que eu lhe avalie como solução rsrs Não sei usar este site muito bem ainda. Abraços.

Comment: @PedroDaher Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente a sua pasta ANDROID_HOME está apontando para uma pasta que não existe. Verifique o caminho da pasta, se estiver setada, ou se não crie a variável e aponte para a pasta do SDK.